# How to enable HK2 TopicDistributionService in jersey 2.15?

Tags: java, jersey, jersey-2.0, event-bus, hk2

I having a problem trying to enable [Hk2 Events](https://hk2.java.net/2.3.0/events.html) in jersey.

ResourceConfig:

```
import org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.TopicDistributionModule;

public class Application extends ResourceConfig {
    public Application() throws IOException {
        super(Application.class);
        register(TopicDistributionModule.class);
    }
}
```

Resource:

```
@Path("/")
public class MainResource {
    @Inject
    private Topic<MyClass> myClassTopic;

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public String index() {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

And I get an error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: There is no implementation of the TopicDistributionService to distribute the message
  at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.TopicImpl.publish(TopicImpl.java:79) ~[hk2-locator-2.3.0.jar:?]
  at ... MainResource.index(MainResource.java:21) ~[classes/:?]
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_20]
```

Comment: The hk2 part of this looks ok.  That should be all you need to do to get your topics working.  You might try this https://hk2.java.net/2.4.0-b08/apidocs/org/glassfish/hk2/utilities/ServiceLocatorUtilities.html#dumpAllDescriptors%28org.glassfish.hk2.api.ServiceLocator%29 in your MainResource (inject the ServiceLocator and then run that method on it in an @PostConstruct) to see if the expected services are there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`TopicDistributionModule`](https://hk2.java.net/2.4.0-b08/apidocs/org/glassfish/hk2/utilities/TopicDistributionModule.html) is an [`AbstractBinder`](https://hk2.java.net/2.4.0-b08/apidocs/org/glassfish/hk2/utilities/binding/AbstractBinder.html), which from my understanding should be registered as an instance, not by class. This

```
register(new TopicDistributionModule());
```

should get rid of the exception, as it register the default `TopicDistributionService`. From there it's just a matter of making sure you have a "live" subscriber when you publish the event/message